# How to uninstall Elm package?

Tags: elm

After I install an elm package by executing

```
elm package install packagename
```

Is there a way to uninstall the elm package besides manually deleting the dependency in elm-package.json?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

currently the only way to remove a package is to delete the dependency in elm-package.json

Answer (score 5):

Remove corresponding line from `elm-package.json` and run `elm-package install`. It'll ask first and then remove the package in question.

Comment: Where does `elm-package` come from? I have Elm 0.19 and I don't have such executable.

Comment: The Elm 0.19 equivalent is just `elm install`. The CLI was changed a bit in that release.

Answer (score 4):

The [elm-json](https://github.com/zwilias/elm-json) project provides an 'uninstall' option that seems to handle things properly, eg. moving them to 'indirect' dependencies when needed, otherwise removing them completely.

It is written by [zwilias](https://github.com/zwilias/) who is on the core team though the project includes a disclaimer that it work in progress.

In can be installed via npm. The project recommends:

> npm install --global elm-json